# Jquery mobile UI issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm facing an issue with Jquery mobile page .

My page contains an left panel ,

header files are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

when i loaded the page in eclipse web browser, it works normally and then tired same page with  the emulator(API 18 & 19), chrome & Firefox, here the page contains multiple header and footer..[image: imageforthefiles]

My full page(code)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-  scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">

    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">

        <a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
        <h1>My PAGE</h1>
        <a href="#myPopupDialog" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-theme="b"
            data-transition="flip" data-position-to="window">Logout</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-theme="b">
        <h3 align="center">Menu</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="#" target="testframe">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="testframe">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="testframe">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="testframe">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <iframe src="panel.html" name="testframe" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">FOOTER </div>
    </div>
```

How I solve this issue? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you post the html code?

Comment: @AmilaIddamalgoda..please  refer the code and kindly help me

Comment: Did u refresh the browser! because it works fine in both irefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try to **clear browser cache** and refresh. This works fine..

**In firefox**

[image]

**In Chrome**

Comment: Don't know the problem is with the emulator?This works fine with other browsers..I tried it dude! :(

Comment: Thanks @Amila.... I solved the issue .There is an error with code          <iframe src="panel.html" name="testframe" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: Really thanks @Amila to guide me... I solved the issue.. The problem is with my code. I'm referring the "panel.html" in the frame ,that's why it shows the header as multiple. <iframe src="panel.html" name="testframe" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"></iframe>, by removing src="panel.html" ,it seems to be working correctly